# increment object name with numbers in a loop

Tags: php

I am having trouble to increment the name of an object within a loop but the following doesn't not seem to work

I need to increment `$serie1->addPoint` to `$serie2->addPoint`, `$serie3->addPoint` etc..

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($users as $agent) {
  $serie{$i}->addPoint...
  $i +=1;
}
```

I get an error `Notice: Undefined variable: serie in`

I also tried `$serie.$i->addPoint...` but that produced an error as well `Fatal error: Call to a member function addPoint()`.

However, it does work if I manually assign the increments like so `$serie1->addPoint` etc..

Comment: It should be `${'serie'.$i}`

Comment: Where you declared ` $serie`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be : `$serie{$i}`

It should be: `${'serie'.$i}`

A short [Demo](https://eval.in/574103)

Comment: thanks, thats what i was looking for!